# After login user list is not showing in meteor?

Tags: meteor

After login user details is not showing.But if I use

```
Meteor.userId();
```

its showing the userid
But if I use

```
Meteor.user();
```

Its showing undefined.Why it so?

Comment: Are you logging these from within a template or by hand in the web console? If it's the former, it would be helpful to show the context.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor.userId() would've been set already, Meteor.user() would not have its subscription fullfilled on page load.  What you would need is to wrap it in

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
   const currentUser = Meteor.user()
   ... code that needs the current user.
})
```